# How to compile ts files in public folder in a next.js project

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a next.js project and I want to make a little game in my public folder. The next.js project is a typescript project and all the tsx files work correctly.
I tried to implement ts files in my public folder as well, but they don't get compiled correctly

my folder structure is the following:
rootfolder/pages/game.tsx
rootfolder/public/game/app.ts

I already ran tsc tsc public/game/app.ts to compile the ts file to a javascript file. The error message I get in the browser is:
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: exports is not defined

I don't know how to get around this.

My files currently look like this:

```
game.tsx

import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';

export default function Game() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>My Game</title>
      </Head>
      <Script type='module' src='game/app.js' />

      <div className='h-[100vh] bg-gray-600 flex justify-center items-center'>
        <div className='game-container scale-125'>
          <canvas
            className='game-canvas border-2 border-gray-300'
            width='700px'
            height='400px'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
app.ts 
console.log('hi');

export default {};
```

```
app.js 
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
console.log('hi');
exports["default"] = {};
```

```
ts.config 
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "public/game/app.js",
    "public/game/app.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: you have compiled it correctly, however module imports/exports are a nodejs thing and do not exist in the browser environment. You need to use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle the files into one so the browser can use them

Comment: I have never done this before, is there any resource on this I could use that describes the set-up? Thanks for your answer (:

Comment: the webpack documentation is the best place to start, I linked it above. if that doesnt help you you can always google webpack tutorials on youtube